# How to decode a json object

Tags: php, json, rest

This might be simple to some but a challenge to me. Well from a documentation, I am getting JSON object in the body of the POST request. The format is shown below.

Question how do I decode the json object when they have not given the variable name of the json object. I thought I would get a variable name so that I would decode this way `$data = json_decode($jsonFromSource);`

I can not figure out a way to do the same, anyone? Thanks.

**Direction from documentation: The POST request will be sent to a URL provided by the enterprise. The following POST parameters that will be passed will be as follows

The parameters passed above will be contained in a JSON object in the body of the POST request.**   Link to the brief documentation https://app.kopokopo.com/push_api

```
{
   "service_name" : "MPESA",
   "business_number" : "888555",
   "transaction_reference" : "DE45GK45"
   "internal_transaction_id" : 3222
   "transaction_timestamp" : "2013-03-18T13:57:00Z"
   "transaction_type" : "Paybill"
   "account_number" : "445534"
   "sender_phone" : "+254903119111"
   "first_name" : "John"
   "middle_name" : "K"
   "last_name" : "Doe"
   "amount" : 4000
   "currency" : "KES"
   "signature" : "dfafwerewKkladaHOKJdafdf"
}
```

Comment: How do you get the data initially?

Comment: I am passing an url to a dashboard, from there they will send me the data.

Comment: https://app.kopokopo.com/push_api here is the link to the documentation. Kindly have a look @RamRaider

Comment: @bmm

    `$data = file_get_contents ('your url here');
    $json = json_decode($data);`

Comment: @BenseidSeid the `your url here` part is what url exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are initially retrieving the data - perhaps this will help?

```
$url='http://www.example.com/api/feed.json';
$data=file_get_contents( $url );
$json=json_decode( $data,true );
foreach( $json as $param => $value ) echo $param, $value, '<br />';
```

Comment: Hello @RamRaider problem I dont have the link to the feeder url. Here is the brief documentation. Kindly have a look https://app.kopokopo.com/push_api Thank you.

Comment: @bmm take a look at the example in the documentation

Comment: This is less of a "how do I decode a json object" and more of a "How do I make a curl POST request with loads of parameters and decode the response"

Comment: You mean the curl example? @BenseidSeid ... Getting the values from it is my problem. Honestly I have no idea how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

KOPOKOPO will push below payload to you which is not JSON

```
"service_name=M-PESA&business_number=888555&transaction_reference=DE45GK45&internal_transaction_id=3222&transaction_timestamp=2013-03-18T13%3A57%3A00Z&transaction_type=Paybill&account_number=445=K.&last_name=Doe&amount=4000&currency=KES"
```

You could then encode like this :

```
$callbackJSONData = json_encode($_POST);
```

Result will be ...

```
{"service_name":"M-PESA","business_number":"888555","transaction_reference":"DE45GK45","internal_transaction_id":"3222","transaction_timestamp":"2013-03-18T13:57:00Z","transaction_type":"Paybill","account_number":"445=K.","last_name":"Doe","amount":"4000","currency":"KES"}

$jdata = json_decode($post,true);

   /*
   * We get details from $_POST only
   */
   $first_name = $jdata["first_name"];
   $middle_name = $jdata["middle_name"];
   $last_name = $jdata["last_name"];
   $paid_amount       = $jdata["amount"];
   $paying_phone_number = str_replace('+254', '0', preg_replace('/[^0-9+]/', '', $jdata["sender_phone"]));
   $transactionID       = $jdata["internal_transaction_id"];
   $transactionrefID        = str_replace('-','',$jdata["service_name"]);
   $MpesaCode = $jdata["transaction_reference"];
   $providerCurrency = $jdata["currency"];
   $providerSignature = $jdata["signature"];
   $payment_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($jdata["transaction_timestamp"])); 
   $payment_time_at = date("Y-M-d",strtotime(NOW)) .' at '.date("H:i A",strtotime(NOW));
   $payment_type = $jdata['transaction_type'];
   $payment_destination = $jdata['business_number'];
```